# Need to do dump & convert between Latin1 and UTF-8 in MySQL if existing data is all ASCII?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I need to convert my application's so that just the text fields use UTF-8 for an encoding. It's fine if everything else is Latin1, as it is right now. The DB was created a long time ago long before I got here, and long before the group had any ambitions of internationalizing the app...

My initial plan was to dump the schema and data separately, regex the schema to modify the text field definitions to use UTF-8, re-import the schema and then the data. I wrote a script to do it and it worked as expected.

The problem was that this process took a long time when I ran it on an old snapshot of our production data ( > 2 hours ). I/O is obviously the bottleneck -- getting the dumps in and out were the bulk of that time. Granted, this was on my workstation and not a machine with more horsepower, but I'm concerned that even with a more powerful machine I won't be able to convert my (much larger) current production database within our weekly maintenance window, which is the only time the site can be down for a long stretch.

Then I realized maybe I don't actually have to use the dump and convert strategy. Since our site currently only has English users, our text data doesn't contain any special characters (not even accented characters, it seems). Because of the overlap between the Latin1 and Unicode code points, shouldn't I be OK just ALTER TABLE'ing each table to change text fields' encodings? Or, is there some other issue that will have me doing the dump-and-convert thing anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to change the columns to type `BLOB`, and then change them back to `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` or whatnot, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name BLOB;
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name ~~~~~ CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

where `~~~~~` is the type that you want, e.g. `VARCHAR(20)` (which, by the way, means "20 characters", and fortunately not "20 bytes").

The reason I suggest going via `BLOB` is that if you just did this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name ~~~~~ CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

then MySQL would try to update every single record to convert it from Latin-1 to UTF-8 — which would be correct, but unnecessary, and slow. (The going-via-`BLOB` approach is [what the documentation recommends doing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html#id924979) when your column is defined as `CHARACTER SET latin1` but, wrongly, contains UTF-8 data, so as to avoid an erroneous conversion. In your case the conversion isn't erroneous, but it's still unnecessary.)

It's probably also best to drop any indices beforehand and re-create them afterwards.

**Important disclaimer:** You should test the above supposition, using the old snapshot that you mention. It's possible that changing to `BLOB` and back will *also* be slow and expensive, in which case I imagine you're better off just doing the single conversion. I think this will depend on the storage engine.

By the way, I'd be interested to hear the results of your test. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, using `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name` changes the default table character set as well as all the text columns. However, I only want to change the text columns. That doc still proved useful though, by noting `ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_varchar_col VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;` However, it seems that with this method (unlike CONVERT) there's the possibility that things might break because the data type conversion didn't happen?

Comment: What I mean is, using the TEXT column example from that doc, if I just ALTER TABLED, wouldn't I be limiting the max string length for this column to (65536 bytes/3 bytes per char) = 21845 characters? Maybe none of the data in our current TEXT columns is even near that length, but even so by doing this future developers will have to be aware the promise of the TEXT column's max length will be broken.

Comment: @hitstuff: Sorry, I think I didn't express myself well. I was *not* suggesting that you use `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name`; in fact, I was specifically suggesting that you *not* do it that way. I'll try to rewrite my answer in a way that's hopefully more clear, and then comment back.

Comment: @hitstuff: I've rewritten my answer. Hopefully it's more intelligible now.

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite! I definitely get what you're saying now. I'll give a go at testing this out and I'll report how it works.